# How to fork the mainnet

Tags: testing, forks

I'm pretty new to Ethereum.
I'm trying to write a simple dapp, which can deposit and withdrawal from aave.
In order to communicate create the contract first I need to fork the mainnet.

I'm not exactly sure how to do it.
I created an infura project (Not sure if I need to do anything to fork the aave contracts)

I spawned an ganache-cli like so:

```
npm i -g ganache-cli https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{myprojectID}}
```

I'm a bit confused on how to connect though.  Is this now running on my localhost? Or Do I need to add a network to metamask for `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{myprojectID}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--fork` flag

```bash
$ npx ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{myprojectID}}
```

The Ganache instance would still run on `localhost` but you should be able to get data from the mainnet. Hope this helps.

Comment: quick question, in the infura project do I need to setup anything or will it automatically fork the latest mainnet, e.g aave is already there

Comment: Ganache would fork the mainnet from the latest block. If you would like to fork from a specific block number, then you would append it at the end of the URL with @.

```bash
$ npx ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{myprojectID}}@<block-num>
```